# can I get some documents from firestore simultaneously using Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to get some documents from Firestore. in my callable cloud function, instead of waiting getting document one by one, await one by one, I use Promise.all so I can get all documents faster, like this

```
        const promises = []

        upcomingEventIDs.forEach( upcomingEventIDs => {

            const p = db.collection("events")
            .where("eventID","==",upcomingEventIDs)
            .where("isActive","==",true)
            .where("hasBeenApproved","==",true)
            .where("isCancelled","==",false)
            .get()

            promises.push(p)
        })

        const latestEventDataSnapshot = await Promise.all(promises)
```

and then I want to loop the document snapshots I just get, and here is the problem

```
    latestEventDataSnapshot.docs.forEach( doc => { // <-- error in this line

        

    })
```

I have an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

what is wrong in here ? what should I do to get the documents that I just get from Firestore ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you get an *array*, which doesn't itself have a docs property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get) method returns a Promise that resolves with a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

Since [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) "returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises", `latestEventDataSnapshot` is an Array of `QuerySnapshot`s and you need to loop over it, for example as follows:

```
    const latestEventDataSnapshot = await Promise.all(promises)

    latestEventDataSnapshot.forEach(querySnapshot => {

        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(queryDocumentSnapshot => {

            console.log(queryDocumentSnapshot.data());
            //...

        })

    })
```